ARC type Breaker Keeps Tripping even without anything plugged in or turned on
I have a breaker that is connected to 2 rooms in my house (bedrooms)  Came home one day and my daughter tells me that there was no power in her room.  I flipped the breaker, and it stayed on for a few minutes, then tripped again.  I went in the attic and looked for chewed on wires from squirrels or racoons.  Couldn't find anything on any of the wires that I saw. I swapped out the breaker from the other bedroom and it stayed on for a while.  With the overhead light on.  That lasted 2 days, and then it tripped again. I had my daughter unplug everything in this room and the adjacent room.  Nothing plugged in, lights off.  Went on a short vacation, came home.  Used a plug tester (plug in and little lights to show if there is a short, miswired, reversed hot and neutral, etc)  That test came out fine.  Nothing wired incorrectly.  Flipped the breaker back on, and it didn't trip.  Everything seemed ok.  Turned everything off, and when she returned, the breaker was tripped.  What boggles my mind is that nothing was plugged in and the lights were off.  I asked her if when they went to turn the light on, did it come on and shut right off, and she said no, nothing happened.  The house is not old.  Built in 2006 and is well maintained.
What can be making this trip when everything is turned off?
Wouldn't a short, trip the breaker as soon as I turned it back on?
Its almost like a slow blow fuse.

Water leak? Something just barely not touching that occasionally vibrates into contact? Best suggestion I have is to start disconnecting branches of this circuit until you figure out where the issue is arising.

What specific arc fault breaker in what specific panel?

Arc fault breakers work by analyzing the waveform looking (more appropriately, "listening") for waveforms ("sounds") of arcing.  If you've ever had a faulty headphone cable that makes a crinkle-crunch sound, or heard the same from a mike or speaker, that.
This typically happens from a faulty appliance, or from bad wiring in the walls which is not making a reliable connection.  If it were left to fester, it would overheat and potentially start a fire.
That said, there's more than one way for an AFCI breaker to trip.  They continue to trip for overload or short circuit, and most AFCIs also have a weak ground fault detector, like a mini-GFCI, so they can trip the way GFCIs do as well.  And fortunately, most modern A/GFCIs have a procedure for reading out the cause of the trip, so you can follow the right troubleshooting path.   Google your breaker's model number and see if you can find instructions on that.
If it's AFCI....
As of today, the gold-standard and mandatory way to tighten screws on receptacles is with a torque screwdriver.
A lot of builder-grade (<75 cent) receptacles are put in with "backstabs" where the wire is jabbed in a hole, a cheap and not very reliable connection method.
The latest sockets are Leviton Decora Edge, which if you can endure the 1970s aesthetics of Decora, have "lever-nut" connections similar to Wago lever-nuts, that are well-regarded.   These avoid the need for torque screwdrivers without being the awful "backstabs".
So going around and re-doing socket and switch connections is a good start on chasing a transient AFCI trip.

You should consider WHY arc-fault breakers are in code
To prevent fires, caused by arcing, typically at a badly connected junction between wires in the walls. A classic cause is using backstab connections to save 3 seconds or so when installing outlets, switches, etc. Other classics are a loose wire nut (marrette) with the rarities being nail in cable that manages to make an arc, not a dead short, or rodents chewing on things in a place where it manages to start arcing. MOST problems will be found in junction boxes.
So while one possibility is a faulty breaker, one possibility is a correctly functioning breaker doing its job, so your house isn't burning down. You (if comfortable and sufficiently knowledgable working in the breaker box) or your electrician can try swapping two arc fault breakers of the same amperage to see if the problem follows the breaker or the circuit, or just swapping in a new arc-fault breaker to see if the problem goes away.
Often there will be signs of arc damage where arcing is occuring - soot, burned plastic, melted insulation, discolored plastic insulation. Usually you won't see them until you (with the breaker switched off) open the junction box to have a look.
A regular, non-arc fault breaker will tolerate arcing at or below its rated current without blowing, as it only responds to amperage. An arc can be small, but is always very hot.
MOST arc fault breakers have some sort of "code" to tell you what caused them to trip. A pattern of blinking LEDs or something like that. You should research yours and see why it says it is tripping.
